# Hotcakes DropDown choice required display asterisk

Tags: dotnetnuke

We have a requirement to display an asterisk on the product drop-down list choice if it has been marked required in the admin interface. Is there a way, we can determine if a dropdown option has been marked required in the product view?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add something in the Products view "/HotcakesViews/YOURVIEWSET/Views/Products/_ProductDetails.cshtml"

I can't remember what the default view has but this is what I have done:

```
@if (opt.IsRequired){ <span class="required">*</span> }
```

This needs to be in the loop that goes through all the product options. It looks something like this:

```
foreach (var opt in Model.LocalProduct.Options)
```